# Boxplot with pandas groupby multiindex, for specified sublevels from multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

Ok so I have a dataframe which contains timeseries data that has a multiline index for each columns. Here is a sample of what the data looks like and it is in csv format. Loading the data is not an issue here.

[image]

What I want to do is to be able to **create a boxplot with this data grouped according to different catagories in a specific line of the multiindex. For example if I were to group by 'SPECIES' I would have the groups, 'aq', 'gr', 'mix', 'sed' and a box for each group at a specific time in the timeseries**.

I've tried this:

```
grouped = data['2013-08-17'].groupby(axis=1, level='SPECIES')
grouped.boxplot()
```

but it gives me a boxplot (flat line) for each point in the group rather than for the grouped set. Is there an easy way to do this? I don't have any problems grouping as I can aggregate the groups any which way I want, but I can't get them to boxplot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think I figured it out, maybe this will be helpful to someone:

```
grouped = data['2013-08-17'].groupby(axis=1, level='SPECIES').T
grouped.boxplot()
```

Basically groupby output needed to be transposed so that the boxplot showed the right grouping:

[image]

Answer (score 68):

this code:

```
data['2013-08-17'].boxplot(by='SPECIES')
```

Will not work, as boxplot is a function for a DataFrame and not a Series.

While in Pandas > 0.18.1 the boxplot function has the argument `columns` which defines from what column the data is taken from.

So

```
data.boxplot(column='2013-08-17',by='SPECIES')
```

should return the desired result.

An example with the Iris dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/pandas/tests/io/data/csv/iris.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
plt.suptitle('')
data.boxplot(column=['SepalLength'], by='Name', ax=ax)
```

creates:

[image: Boxplot iris dataset with pandas]

```
plt.suptitle('')
```

turns off the annoying automatic subtitle. And of course
the column arguments accepts lists of columns... so

```
data.boxplot(column=['SepalLength', 'SepalWidth'], by='Name', ax=ax)
```

also works.

Comment: This is really nice, but how to make each type colored differently ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in version 0.16:

```
data['2013-08-17'].boxplot(by='SPECIES')
```